# He then sought God in different worldly things whom he revered them and praised them

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, word-usage, sentence

> He then sought God in different worldly things whom he revered them and praised them.

Can someone please let me know if I have made correct usage of 'Whom' in the above sentence. Correction of this sentence will be appreciable instead of changing it wholly.

Comment: Who does "whom" refer to?

Comment: to the things he revered and praised. Confusion is whether 'them' is pertinent here not.

Comment: You cannot refer to inanimate things as "whom."

Answer (score 1):

No. There are a couple of mistakes here.

1. "Whom" refers to a person. In your sentence it can only refer to "God", not "things". For "things", you should use "that" or "which".
2. You have two different pronouns ("whom" and "them") for the "things". Your structure uses a relative clause, so "whom"/"which" are correct.

A correct version would be either:

> He then sought God in different worldly things that he revered and praised.
>
> He then sought God in different worldly things, which he revered and praised.

(Many usage experts insist that "which" should only come after a comma, as shown here, but it is common to omit the comma.)

The basic structure is this:

> He then sought God in different worldly things. He revered them and praised them.

This sounds quite stilted. You could reduce that effect by joining the sentences together, either with a relative clause (as above) or with punctuation:

> He then sought God in different worldly things; he revered them and praised them.
>
> He then sought God in different worldly things—he revered them and praised them.

Comment: Thanks a lot pederick. It's much clear now..!

Comment: @HassanRaza If you find the answer correct, you should mark it as accepted (check the [tour]). You might want to wait one or two days, though, to see if there are comments correcting the answer or a better answer is written.

Comment: It’s not whether there’s a comma or not, but whether it’s a restrictive or non-restrictive clause.

Comment: @Jim: Thanks, I knew there was a proper explanation. Still, same result. (Except I've just found at least one random website that says restricted clauses are "usually" set off with commas, so I guess not all guides are that prescriptive!)